# Spotlight taking a lot of power on macOS

Tags: spotlight, macos, energy

I recently installed macOS, but I have noticed that "Spotlight.app" has had high CPU usage. It is not indexing.

[image: macOS Activity Monitor]

[image: Power menu bar item]

Answer (score 1):

The *Average Energy Impact* column in Activity Monitor takes past energy usage into account. For example for me it shows 23,87 for Time Machine even though it is not backing up at the moment.

Apparently Spotlight has been very active but has now finished indexing.